# Getting No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myPersistentUnit , even if the persistent.xml is under '/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/'

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

Getting No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myPersistentUnit , even if the 'persistent.xml' is under '/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/'. 
My war is deployed on the Tomcat server.

Here is my persistent.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myPersistentUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.login.entity.LoginEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/hibernatedb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my code :

```
package com.login.entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class LoginEntityManager {

    private static LoginEntityManager loginEntityManager;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private LoginEntityManager() {

    }

    public static LoginEntityManager getLoginEntityManager() {
        if (loginEntityManager == null) {
            loginEntityManager = new LoginEntityManager();
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistentUnit");
            loginEntityManager.setEntityManager(factory.createEntityManager());
        }

        return loginEntityManager;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>login</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>login</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: errm, well i'd expect there are more than 1 jar required for "Hibernate"

Comment: i have all these jars : antlr-2.7.6.jar; commons-collections-3.1.jar ; dom4j-1.6.1.jar ; hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar; hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar; 
hibernate-entitymanager.jar; hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar; javassist-3.9.0.jar; 
jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar; jta-1.1.jar; slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar;  xxx-jdbc-driver.jar